# Proxy settings should be done at maven level or IDE level or both?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, proxy, http-proxy

I have a java project built with maven. Turns out there is a proxy setting to be used in order to download the dependencies from Nexus. We have one proxy setting that is defined inside ~/.m2/settings.xml, and then we have another one define at IDE level which is IntelliJ idea in my case.

I want to know is it required to define proxy settings inside both IDE and settings.xml.
If not, and let's say a user defines the proxy settings at both places, which settings will take preference?

Comment: may I ask the reason for downvote?

Comment: This question exactly matches a problem I investigated today. It turns out that proxy settings done in IntelliJ are not propagated to maven. There should be a warning message next to the setting ("plug-ins might not be affected"). I have no idea where the downvotes come from.

Answer (score 2):

yes when using maven you should configure the proxy in the .m2/settings.xml

[Maven settings.xml](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html)

AND

additionally you need to browse in Project Settings in IntelliJ File=>Settings=>Maven

and you must check the control box besides User settings guide  that points to your modified settings.xml

[image: maven settings intellij]

GOOD LUCK

Comment: So the proxy settings defined at IntelliJ idea level is not required, if I define the same in settings.xml?

Comment: yes just tell intellij to use your modified settings.xml then it should have access to repository.. thanks